# Akka: update ActorSystem configuration dynamically

Tags: java, scala, akka

I have one long lived `ActorSystem` with quite a few child actors ~3000. I am creating the `ActorSystem` using the `ActorSystem.apply("system", config);` call to the `ActorSystem`.

My configuration is held externally to my application and can be altered at any point (think DB username/password etc).

How can I update the config of an already running `ActorSystem` when my external config changes?

Comment: I have to research this one. It is an interesting issue, and I'm surprised it hasn't come up more often. I think the behavior will have to be provided by overriding the existing implementation. Is the DB config for a specific akka module? akka-persistence perhaps?

Comment: The main config that I'm interested in is the usernames and passwords for persistence. But, I'd like to be able to update any akka config e.g. turning on/off actor debug statements etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration of the `ActorSystem` is immutable, so that means that if you want to change configuration that Akka itself reads and uses you will have to terminate the ActorSystem and start a new one to pick the changed configuration up. There is no built in tool that does this.

If it is configuration for your own actors you could either have them read the configuration they need from somewhere else than the system config, so that you can trigger to re-load/parse the configuration or implement a protocol to the specific set of actors that allow you to re-configure them with a message.

In either case you would have to implement watching the configuration for changes yourself, could be done through regular JDK APIs for filesystem watching or perhaps based on the Alpakka directory changes `Source` - https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/file.html#listening-to-changes-in-a-directory